# Web API 2 - block all external calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to block all calls to my web api that are not coming from the web-site itself?

I mean if my MVC app runs at : http://www.domain.com and the web api at http://www.domain.com/api/service, I want the web api to accept calls only from current application only. No external calls allowed.

I will guess maybe a message handler will be the best in this case?

Comment: Have you read about cors? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: CORS is used to tell a browser where cross origin requests should be coming from, its up to the client to decide whether to enforce CORS or not.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Controller for error page and catch all garbage requests like this:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("block", "{*something}", new { controller = "Error", action = "Get" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement token authorization using a delegating handler.

```
 public class AuthorizationHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public AuthorizationHeaderHandler(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
    {

        //set the inner handler
        InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(httpConfiguration); 
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> apiKeyHeaderValues = null;

        if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("X-ApiKey", out apiKeyHeaderValues))
        {
            var apiKeyHeaderValue = apiKeyHeaderValues.First();

            //based on the api-key get username whose session is stil valid.

            var username = //code to get user based on apiKeyHeaderValue;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                var usernameClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username);
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[] {usernameClaim}, "ApiKey");
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //You don't have an ApiKey from the request... can't proceed
            var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
                new {Message = "You are not Authorized to access that resource"}); //new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
            tsc.SetResult(response);
            return tsc.Task;
        }

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

You can then register the handler in the WebApiConfig

```
 public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Init(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
           constraints:null,
           handler: new AuthorizationHeaderHandler(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)
       );


    }
}
```

you can then setup your login controller to authorize a user and assign then a token

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{



    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Login([FromBody] UserDTO userDTO)
    {
        // first perform user authentication.

        // clear all existing tokens for this  authorized user


        //create security token and save token of current user
        //You can store this in a database and use a repository to create these.
        // Tokens can be guids.  
        // await token creation

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {LogingResult = result, token = token});
    }
}
```

Once that user has the token, it can be used for Api requests by adding to the request header. In Angularjs it can take the following form.

```
'use strict';
```

(function () {

```
angular.module('App', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);

//interceptor for server calls

var httpInterceptor = function ($q, $window, $location) {
    return function(promise) {
        var success = function(response) {
            return response;
        };

        var error = function(response) {
            if (response.status === 403) {
                $location.url('/login');
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        };

        return promise.then(success, error);
    };

}

httpInterceptor['$inject'] = ['$q', '$window', '$location'];
angular.module('App').factory('httpInterceptor', httpInterceptor);



var api = function ($http, $cookies) {
    return {
        init: function (token) {
            $http.defaults.headers.common['X-ApiKey'] = token || $cookies.token;
        }
    };
}

api['$inject'] = ['$http', '$cookies'];

angular.module('App').factory('api',  api);
```

})();

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is definitely possible.  You have to create a custom handler and filter for the RemoteIpAddress found in the request.  Here's an implementation using Owin Self-Host:

```
 public class CustomerHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request?.GetClientIpAddress() != "127.0.0.1")
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
        }

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}

public static class HttpReqestMessageExtension
{
    public static string GetClientIpAddress(this HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if (!request.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_OwinContext")) return null;

        dynamic owinContext = request.Properties["MS_OwinContext"];
        return owinContext.Request.RemoteIpAddress;
    }

}
```

If you where using ASP.Net then you would use the appropriate key => MS_HttpContext

Now you simply add this to the startup of your Api:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomerHandler());
```